# How to set the biased parameter of LogisticClassifier constructor in Stanford NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, stanford-nlp, logistic-regression

I am using the LogisticClassifier of Stanford NLP. When building a new instance of [LogisticClassifier](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/LogisticClassifier.html), it is required to set a boolean parameter "biased" in the constructor. The default value is "false". What does it mean? How should I set it?

```
LogisticClassifier<Integer, Integer> classifier = new LogisticClassifier<Integer, Integer>( false )
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not well documented. However it seems that you should use `LogisticClassifierFactory` to create instances of `LogisticClassifier`. I didn't find a description of the biased parameter in the API either. My guess is that it is used to switch between fitting with, and without offset in the linear term. Just a guess, though.